# Azure Container Instances cannot access to docker images

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances

I just recently had a problem when trying to deploy the new docker images to Azure Container Instances. The Azure portal return this message when I was trying to restart the container groups:

```
'BadRequest':'InaccessibleImage':'The image 'xxxx' in container group 'xxx' is not accessible. Please check the image and registry credential.
```

The same error showed up when I used the "az container create" command. I am sure that the credential is correct and everything worked fine a couple of days ago.

I am not sure if there is a connection problem from Azure to Docker or if there are any breaking changes in Azure Container Instances. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Comment: any updates? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

As surprising as it sounds, ACI does not support images with no manifests or with OCI manifests when fetched from Docker Hub.

One way to work around this is to pull the public image into ACR and then have ACI pull that same image from ACR instead.

Also, AKS doesn't suffer from this bug.

Answer (score -1):

I've been having the same problem for the last 6 hours as well. I believe there is an issue with Azure but I do not know how to verify this at the moment.

Comment: Can confirm I am having the same problem as well, I have issued a Bug Report in the GitHub Issues for AzureCLI hoping for a response ASAP.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/18596